# req.signedCookie returns empty object despite it being stored correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, jwt

After I have my AuthCookie saved in the browser [correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vbvZ.png)
I attempt to read it from express (for auth check purposes), but i get an empty object despite it working normally if I do it from Postman.

How the cookie is requested:

```
const formData = //grab it from form

 fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login",{
        method:"POST",
        mode:"cors",
        credentials:"include",
        headers:{
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
            'withCredentials':true,
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(formData)
    })
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(res=>{
            console.log(res)
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

How the cookie is set:

```
res.cookie("AuthCookie", accessToken, {
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000),
  httpOnly: false, //change this later
  signed:true
});
```

How I attempt to read it:

```
const isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
  let token = req.signedCookies;
  console.log(token);
  //verifying token etc
}
```

output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdYxv.png).

I have tried not signing it and the problem is exactly the same. Am I missing something here?
Ill post any additional code if needed :)

**edit** I fixed this by using `credentials:"include"` in headers of the GET request as well.

Comment: use `cookie-parser` middleware. check this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/req-cookies-and-req-signedcookies-in-express-js/

Comment: i am already using cookie-parser :(